# Java - Use Scanner to read big text files

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a very big text file with customer information. I would like to read all the customer information from the text file.

This is how my text file is organized:

```
Costomer 1:
Name: 
Erik Andersson
Adress:
Street1
Phone number:
085610540

Costomer 2:
Name: 
Lars Larsson
Adress:
Street1
Phone number:
085610540
```

I would like to be able read all the customer information. Is there any good way to it with? I have read about Scanner and Pattern and was wondering if it is good idea to use them in this case? My text file is very big and contains hundreds of customers.

Dose any one have any idea how I could read all the information from the text file? I have created a class with customer variabled, I only need help with the reading from the text file. I want to read the information in an organized way.

All help is very very appreciated.

Comment: Are you very new at Java? Is this homework?

Comment: "hundreds of customers" isn't big _at all_.

Comment: @GregS - Yes this a homework.

Comment: @Lars012: Not a problem, but the it is considered polite to include a homework tag in the question. I have done so.

Comment: cmon i did all that work for u at least give me the credit for it

Comment: @stas - Of course I will give you credit. Iam testing your code right know.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
public void getEmployees(File f) throws Exception {
    // An ArrayList of your Employee-Object to hold multiple Employees
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    // The reader to read from your File
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath()));
    // This will later contain one single line from your file
    String line = "";

    // Temporary fields for the constructor of your Employee-class
    int number;
    String name;
    String adress;
    String phone;

    // Read the File untill the end is reached (when "readLine()" returns "null")
    // the "line"-String contains one single line from your file.
    while ( (line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
        // See if your Line contains the Customers ID:
        if (line.startsWith("Customer")) {
            // Parse the number to an "int" because the read value
            // is a String.
            number = Integer.parseInt(s.substring("Customer ".length()).substring(0,s.indexOf(':')));
        } else if (line.startsWith("Adress:")) {
            // The Adress is noted in the next line, so we
            // read the next line:
            adress = in.readLine();
        } else if (line.startsWith("Phone number:")) {
            // Same as the Adress:
            phone = in.readLine();
        } else if (line.startsWith("Name:")){
            // Same as the Adress:
            name = in.readLine();
        } else if ( line.equals("") ){
            // The empty line marks the end of one set of Data
            // Now we can create your Employee-Object with the
            // read values:
            employees.add(new Employee(number,name,adress,phone));      
        }
    }
    // After we processed the whole file, we return the Employee-Array
    Employee[] emplyeeArray = (Employee[])employees.toArray();
}
```

Please give +1 and correct for ur hw lol

Comment: I updated your code as it didn't worked. Please also see my post for some advices.

Comment: Thnks for the answer. I was wondering how can I know when I costomer has been read and when the next one should begin? Becuase sometimes there are some empty lines in between costomer information.

Comment: And what about if an adress is spread over more than one line? How can I handle that.

Comment: it already handles if there is a blank line and just keep the adresses one line

Answer (score 0):

As a little extension to [stas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737842/stas) answer:

The originally posted code doesn't work, because a `continue` skips the current loop-iteration. So unless the line starts with `""`, nothing is ever done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering how can I handle if the costomer information is spead over more than one line? For example if the adress is spread over 3 lines and then the Phone number line comes.

Comment: If you have an influence of how the file is formated, use [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) or [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). They are both greatly supported by Java.